# Print N Squared

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, arithmetic, grid

Write a program or function that takes in a non-negative integer N from stdin or as a function argument. It must print or return a string of a hollow ASCII-art square whose sides are each made with N copies of the number N.

#### Specifically:

If N is `0`, no copies of N are used, so there should be no output (or only a single trailing newline).

If N is `1`, the output is:

```
1
```

If N is `2`:

```
22
22
```

If N is `3`:

```
333
3 3
333
```

If N is `4`:

```
4444
4  4
4  4
4444
```

If N is `5`:

```
55555
5   5
5   5
5   5
55555
```

The pattern continues for `6` through `9`.

If N is `10`, the output is:

```
10101010101010101010
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10101010101010101010
```

**Notice that this is not actually square.** It is 10 rows tall but 20 columns wide because `10` is two characters long. This is intended. The point is that each side of the "square" contains N copies of N. **So all inputs beyond `9` will technically be ASCII rectangles.**

For example, if N is `23`, the output is:

```
2323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
23                                          23
2323232323232323232323232323232323232323232323
```

Here are Pastebins of the required outputs for [`99`](http://pastebin.com/raw/Qcas2Qmu), [`100`](http://pastebin.com/raw/1wc2FNmL), [`111`](http://pastebin.com/raw/DGZcHSiS), and [`123`](http://pastebin.com/raw/ajYdGhmw) (they may look wrong in a browser but in a text editor they'll look correct). The output for `1000` is to large for Pastebin but it would have 1000 rows and 4000 columns. **Numbers with 4 or more digits must work just like smaller numbers.**

#### Details:

- N must be written in the usual decimal number representation, with no `+` sign or other non-digits.
- The hollow area must only be filled with spaces.
- No lines should have leading or trailing spaces.
- A single newline after the squares' last line is optionally allowed.
- Languages written after this challenge was made are welcome, they just [aren't eligible to win](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4870/26997).
- **The shortest code in bytes wins!**

Comment: The square for n=10 looks more square than for n=5. Hooray, non-square fonts!

Comment: May we take the integer as a string?

Comment: @Nᴮᶻ Yes you may

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Jolf, <s>31</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
?=1i1ρρ,aii+*3έέi*li
```

This is encoded in the ISO-8859-7 encoding and contains unprintables, so here's a hexdump:

```
0000000: 3f3d 3169 31f1 f12c 6169 692b 2a33 dd05  ?=1i1..,aii+*3..
0000010: dd69 052a 056c 69                        .i.*.li
```

[Try this fiddle online](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Pz0xaTHPgc-BLGFpaSsqM86tBc6taQUqBWxp&input=Mw) or [verify all test cases at once (use the full run button)](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Pz0xaTHPgc-BLGFpaSsqM86tBc6taQUqBWxp&input=MQoKMgoKMwoKNAoKNQoKMTAKCjIz).

This exits with an error for n = 0, which is [allowed by default.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/45151)

Massive thanks to Conor for golfing off <s>4</s> 6! bytes. <sub><sup>inb4 crossed out four still looks like a four comment</sup></sub>

### Explanation

```
?=1i1ρρ,aii+*3έ\x05έi\x05*\x05li

?=1i1                             if input is 1 return 1, otherwise...
       ,aii+*3έ\x05               draw an input x input hollow box of tabs
      ρ            έi             replace all tabs with input
     ρ               \x05*\x05li  replace all spaces with spaces * length of input
```

Comment: How did you generate the hexdump?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I used xxd. You can reverse it with `xxd -r`.

Answer (score 16):

## [Shtriped](http://github.com/HelkaHomba/shtriped), 317 bytes

While I'm making the question, I may as show off my new "purist" language.

```
@ f x
 d x
 f
 @ f x
+ x y
 +
  i x
 @ + y
 h x
} x y
 e 1
 i 1
 d y
 d 1
 d x
 } x y
e 0
e 2
i 2
i 2
e 6
+ 2 2 6
+ 2 6 6
e T
+ 2 2 T
+ 6 T T
e N
t N
e P
+ T 0 P
e L
i L
*
 e x
 *
  + P x x
 @ * T
 h x
~
 } N P 0
 d 0
 i L
 * P
 ~
~
#
 p N
-
 s 6
_
 @ - L
$
 #
 @ _ n
 #
 s 2
@ # N
e n
+ N 0 n
d n
d n
s 2
@ $ n
@ # N
```

<sup>(definitely works in [v1.0.0](https://github.com/HelkaHomba/shtriped/releases/tag/v1.0.0))</sup>

There are no math operations built into Shtriped except increment and decrement. There's also no looping or conditionals, so all of these thing need to be built up from scratch in every program.

That's what my program does, e.g. `@` is essentially a for loop, `+` is an addition function, `}` is `>=`. The actual output is only produced in the last 8 lines of the program.

There are no strings either in Shtriped. You can take in and print out strings, but they are all represented internally as arbitrary precision integers that can only be incremented and decremented. So there's no easy way get the length of the string `10` for filling in the the square center with the right amount of spaces. I had to cobble together the function `~` that effectively computes `floor(log10(N)) + 1` to find the length of N in decimal.

This could probably be golfed a bit more by rearranging where and how which variables are used, but not *that* much more. There's no getting around Shtriped's inherent limitations. (It was never meant to be a golfing language anyway.)

**Commented code (a backslash is a comment):**

```
@ f x \ function that calls f() x times, returns 0
 d x
 f
 @ f x
+ x y \ returns x + y
 +
  i x
 @ + y
 h x
} x y \ returns 1 if x >= y, else 0
 e 1
 i 1
 d y
 d 1
 d x
 } x y

\ declare and set up variables for the numbers 0, 2, 6, 10
e 0 \ 0 is used to help copy values via +
e 2 \ 2 is used for printing newlines
i 2
i 2
e 6 \ 6 is used for printing spaces
+ 2 2 6
+ 2 6 6
e T \ 10 is used for finding the string length of N
+ 2 2 T
+ 6 T T

e N \ declare N
t N \ and set it to what the user inputs

\ all the code from here to the last ~ is for finding the length of N as a string

e P \ P is the current power of 10 (10, 100, 1000...), starting with 10
+ T 0 P
e L \ L will be the length of N in decimal digits
i L

* \ function that returns P times 10 by adding P to itself 10 times
 e x
 *
  + P x x
 @ * T
 h x

~ \ function that increments L and multiplies P by 10 until N < P, at which point L will be the string length of N
 } N P 0 \ the 0 variable can be used as a dummy now since we don't need it anymore
 d 0
 i L
 * P \ multiply P by 10 to 
 ~
~

\ helper functions for displaying the output
# \ simply prints N as a decimal integer
 p N
- \ prints a single space
 s 6
_ \ prints L spaces (L = digit length of N)
 @ - L
$ \ prints one of the central N-2 lines of the square
 #
 @ _ n
 #
 s 2

\ finally, call these functions to display the output
@ # N \ print N copies of N (top line of square)
e n \ declare n and set it to N - 2
+ N 0 n
d n
d n \ if N was 0 or 1 the program will end here, having printed nothing if 0 or just the top line if 1
s 2 \ print a newline
@ $ n \ print the central line of the square N-2 times
@ # N \ print N copies of N (bottom line of square)

\ the output always prints without a trailing newline
```

Answer (score 8):

### Seriously, <s>32</s> <s>31</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
╩╜ó$╝╜Dbu╜╛*n╜¬;╛l*' *╛+╛@+n(
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWp4pWcw7Mk4pWd4pWcRGJ14pWc4pWbKm7ilZzCrDvilZtsKicgKuKVmyvilZtAK24o&input=MTA)

Explanation:

```
╩╜ó$╝╜Dbu╜╛*n╜¬;╛l*' *╛+╛@+n(
╩                              push each input to its own register
                                 (we'll call register 0 "n")
 ╜                             push n to the stack
  ó                            terminate if 0
   $╝                          push str(n) to register 1
                                 (we'll call register 1 "s")
     ╜Dbu╜╛*n                  make min(2,n) copies of s*n (the top and bottom)
                                 (this avoids an extra copy if n is 1)
             ╜¬;               push n-2 twice
                ╛l*' *         push (n-2)*len(s) spaces
                      ╛+╛@+    put s on the front and end of the string (a middle piece)
                           n   push (n-2) total copies of the middle piece
                            (  bring the top piece to the top
```

Answer (score 6):

## C++14, 156 chars

I thought it was a pretty cool solution though obviously can not beat most other entries here.

```c++
#define f for(i=0;i++<n;c<<t);
[](string t){auto&c=cout;int n=stoi(t),i;f c<<'\n';for(i=0;++i<n-1;c<<t,c.width(~-n*size(t)+1),c.fill(0),c<<t+'\n');if(n-1)f}
```

Ungolfed:

```c++
#define f for ( i = 0; i++ < n; c << t ); // print top/bot row
[](string t) {
  auto& c = cout;
  int n = stoi(t), i;
  f // print first row
  c << '\n'; // kind of annoying but no way to get rid of (yes I tried
             // c << '\n'+t instead of c << t+'\n')
  for ( i = 0; ++i < n - 1; ) {
    c << t; // output the number
    // then we we get the width of necessary spaces
    c.width(~-n*size(t)+1); // Equivalent to (n-1)*size(t) + 1, but we save
                            // two bytes since ~- takes precedence over
                            // multiplication
    c.fill(0); // fill with spaces, ' ' == 0
    c << t+'\n';
   }
   if ( n-1 ) f // This if statement is dissapointing 
}
```

And like always, to call the function use `[](string t) { ... }("10");`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73 82</s> 78 bytes

*Saved a4 bytes thanks to @user81655*

```
n=>(a=n[r='repeat'](n),n<2?a:a+`
${n+' '[r](n.length*(n-2))+n}`[r](n-2)+`
`+a)
```

Takes a string, not a number for input.

[Try it online](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3Dn%3D%3E(a%3Dn%5Br%3D'repeat'%5D(n)%2Cn%3C2%3Fa%3Aa%2B%60%0A%24%7Bn%2B'%20'%5Br%5D(n.length*(n-2))%2Bn%7D%60%5Br%5D(n-2)%2B%60%0A%60%2Ba)%0A%0Aalert(%20f(%20'0'%20)%20)%0Aalert(%20f(%20'1'%20)%20)%0Aalert(%20f(%20'2'%20)%20)%0Aalert(%20f(%20'3'%20)%20)%0Aalert(%20f(%20'10'%20)%20)) (all browsers work)

Comment: You can replace `*(n-2)` with `*~-~-n` to save a byte.

Comment: @user81655 thanks, that fixed it

Comment: @Neil thanks but that doesn't appear to save any bytes unfortunately

Comment: Sorry, I must have miscounted.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL),  <s>34</s> <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
:G\2<t!+gQ"@!2GVYX1GVnZ"YX
```

This works with [current release (13.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/13.0.0) of the language/compiler

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OkdcMjx0IStnUSJAITJHVllYMUdWbloiWVg&input=MTA)

```
:            % array [1,2,...,N], where N is input, taken implicitly
G\           % modulo N. Gives [1,2,...,N-1,0]
2<           % smaller than 2? Gives [1,0,...,0,1]
t!           % duplicate, transpose
+            % addition with broadcast. Gives 2D array with nonzeros in the border 
             % and zeros in the interior
gQ           % convert to logical, add 1: twos in the border, ones in the interior
"            % for each column of that array (note the array is a symmetric matrix,
             % so columns and rows are the same)
  @!         %   push column. Transpose into a row        
  2GVYX      %   replace twos by the string representation of N, via regexp
  1GVnZ"YX   %   replace ones by as many spaces as length of that string, via regexp
             % end for each, implicitly
             % display stack contents, implicitly
```

Answer (score 5):

## T-SQL/SQL Server 2012+, <strike>167</strike> 161 bytes

```
DECLARE @ INT = 6;

SELECT IIF(u IN(1,s),REPLICATE(s,s),CONCAT(s,REPLICATE(' ',s-2*LEN(s)),s))
FROM(SELECT @ s)z CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(s)ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)u FROM sys.messages)v
```

Output:

```
666666 
6    6 
6    6  
6    6  
6    6 
666666
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483695?Size=7&opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Enter desired size and click <kbd>Run query</kbd> to get text representation.

Please note that this demo does not display **fixed-width font**. So `7` is thicker than `1`.

---

**EDIT:**

If we treat input as string:

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(10) = '7';

SELECT IIF(u IN(1,s),REPLICATE(s,s),s+REPLICATE(' ',s-2*LEN(s))+s)
FROM(SELECT @ s)z CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(s+0)ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY 1/0)u FROM sys.messages)v
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483693?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Comment: This is very nice, I learned how to shorten some of my other scripts a bit. Didn't know the order by 1/0 and sys.messages

Comment: on a side note.Should the declaration of input parameter really be included when counting the bytes ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I am not sure about counting rules, when SQL is applied but I will ask on meta and let you know.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9126/how-to-count-bytes-with-sql

Comment: You can save a few bytes by making s varchar(like this '6'), then you can replace concat with +.

Comment: Seems you are missing some spaces. I believe you can fix it by writing (s-2)

Comment: Nice techniques! You can use `SPACE()` instead of `REPLICATE(' ', n)` to save a bunch of bytes. Also, @t-clausen.dk is correct, your space counts fails for values of n>9.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 78 bytes

```
n->(s="$n";(p=println)(s^n);[p(s*" "^(n-2)endof(s)*s)for i=2:n-1];n>1&&p(s^n))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and prints the ASCII rectangle to STDOUT. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(n)
    # Save a string version of n
    s = "$n"

    # Print the top line
    println(s^n)

    # Print each middle line
    [println(s * " "^(n-2)endof(s) * s) for i = 2:n-1]

    # Print the last line if there is one
    n > 1 && println(s^n)
end
```

[Try it online](http://goo.gl/9YDL5L)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 100 bytes

```rb
->n{s="";n.times{|i|s+=(i<1||i>n-2?"#{n}"*n :"#{n}#{' '*[(n-2)*n.to_s.size,0].max}#{n}")+$/};puts s}
```

Too bad I couldn't even manage to beat JS. Any further help golfing it down would be appreciated.

Here's a more or less ungolfed version:

```rb
def f(n)
    n.times{|num|
        if num == 0 || num == n-1
            s += "#{n}" * n
        else
            s += "#{n}"+" "*[(n-2)*n.to_s.length,0].max+"#{n}"
        end
        s += "\n"
    }
    puts s
end
```

Comment: You might want to assign a variable to `n.to_s` since you use it so much, giving you `m*n` for the first part and `m+" "*[(n-2)*m.length,0].max+m` for the second part.

Comment: I based a 75-byte version on this answer. (Javascript is currently at 78 bytes) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcgxDoMgFADQ3VP82EFAJIqdbMWDENLYiikDX1N1aMWz06XdXt5ru7/j2MZC4e5bFOt0Wy6kEgKp8P28BxeIu8oQnMKi6jzDxucZZIygkh3BQlLmxeI@toGS5p4eR9Qlr7jkNT9zWRth@8cThgkChgRg3tYFUo3tacfDpP8ZNZqfE4tD/AI "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, 76 bytes

```
.+
$0$*n$0
n(?=n*(\d+))|.
$1_
\d+_
$_¶
T`d` `(?<=¶.*_.*).(?=.*_\d.*¶\d)
\`_
[empty line]
```

Explanation maybe comes tomorrow.

[Try it online here.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJDAkKm4kMApuKD89biooXGQrKSl8LgokMV8KXGQrXwokX8K2ClRgZGAgYCg_PD3Cti4qXy4qKS4oPz0uKl9cZC4qwrZcZCkKXGBfCg&input=MTI)

Comment: It's been a while since tomorrow.

Comment: It's been more than a whole year since tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

### TSQL, <s>112</s> 104 bytes

```
DECLARE @ varchar(10)='12'

PRINT REPLICATE(@,@)+ISNULL('
'+REPLICATE(@+ISNULL(SPACE((@-2)*len(@))+@,'')+'
',@-2)+REPLICATE(@,@),'')
```

> ```
> 1. generating first line
> 2. adding hollow lines + line breaks
> 3. adding last line(when needed)
> ```

Comment: Could you add an explanation for those of us who don't know T-SQL?

Comment: @cat wrote a short explanation, and included a fiddle

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It looks like your byte count might be off: [check here](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#SELECT%20STUFF%28REPLICATE%28x%2Cx%2a2%29%2Cx%2alen%28x%29%2B1%2C0%2C%27%0A%27%2BREPLICATE%28x%2BREPLICATE%28%27%20%27%2C%28x-2%29%2alen%28x%29%29%2Bx%2B%27%0A%27%2Cx-2%29%29%0AFROM%28values%28%273%27%29%29z%28x%29)

Comment: @cat thanks. I was looking for a link for that. However the last line with the FROM is just declaring and assigning value to X, I heard that assigning values and declaring variables doesn't count. Please correct me if i am wrong. I tried to save a few bytes with this assignment of variables. Normal variables are prefixed with **@**, costing 1 extra byte for each time using it

Comment:  [Here is my approach](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79536/44651). Also TSQL :)

Comment: Nice work. Save some bytes with `SPACE()` instead of `REPLICATE(' ', n)`. Also, on my machine it cuts off the output text when @=63 or higher, but I'm not sure if that's your problem or a SSMS client setting.

Comment: @BradC you are right in both cases. management studio has limited output and the space thing has been adjusted. Thanks

Comment: Is it work correclty when n=1?

Comment: @mazzy yes it does - 3. adding last line(when needed)

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 57 bytes

```
nd?.d1-2&N.$z01FlOz2-[lz6Z" "I2-z2-*Dz6Z$O]01F.
z[z6Z]$Of
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=nd%3F%2Ed1-2%26N%2E%24z01FlOz2-%5Blz6Z%22%20%22I2-z2-*Dz6Z%24O%5D01F%2E%0Az%5Bz6Z%5D%24Of&input=100)

#### Explanation

```
n                Read number from input
 d?.             Stop if n=0, continue otherwise
    d1-2&N.      Print 1 and stop if n=1, continue otherwise
           $z    Store top of stack in register (z, which is n)

01F                                   Gosub to second line
   lO                                 Print newline
     z2-                              Push value from register and subtract 2
        [                             Pop k and run body of for loop k times
                                      (Does not run if k <= 0)
         l                            Push a newline
          z6Z                         Push z and convert to string
             " "                      Push a space
                I2-                   Push length of stack minus 2
                   z2-                Push z minus 2
                      *               Pop b,a and push a,b
                       D              Pop k and duplicate top of stack k times
                        z6Z           Push z and convert to string
                           $O         Output whole stack as characters
                             ]        Close for loop
                              01F.    Gosub to second line and stop after returning.


z[   ]       For loop that runs z times
  z6Z        Push z and convert to string
      $O     Output whole stack as characters
        f    Return to position called from
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 26 bytes

```
K*QQjbm++Q**lQ;ttQQttQK
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%0A%0AK%2a%60QQjbm%2B%2BQ%2a%2al%60Q%3BttQQttQK&input=15&debug=0).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman the permalink button seems to be broken

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>79</s> <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```
$_=$.=pop;s/./ /g;print$.x$.,$/,($.,$_ x($.-2),$.,$/)x($.-2),$.>1?$.x$.:''
```

Pretty straightforward. The first commandline argument is taken as the number. Place the script in a file and run with `perl file.pl 1`.

Comment: `shift` can be replaced with `pop`.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>62</s> <s>60</s> 58 + 2 = 60 bytes

```
for$.(1..$_){say$.>1&$.<$_?$_.$"x(y...c*($_-2)).$_:$_ x$_}
```

Requires `-nlE` flags:

```
$ perl -nlE'for$.(1..$_){say$.>1&$.<$_?$_.$"x(y...c*($_-2)).$_:$_ x$_}' <<< 5
55555
5   5
5   5
5   5
55555
```

With spaces added:

```
for$.(1..$_) {
  say(
    $. > 1 & $. < $_
      ? $_ . $"x(length$_*($_-2)) . $_
      : $_ x $_
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 90 bytes

```
x=scan();m=matrix(x,x,x);k=2:(x-1)*(x>2);m[k,k]=format("",w=nchar(x));write(m,"",n=x,s="")
```

---

This creates a matrix of `x*x` size and then fills with spaces of size `nchar(x)` . If `x` smaller than 2, then nothing is being filled.

Comment: I know this is a year later, but...

`x=scan();m=matrix(x,x,x);m[k<--c(1,x),k]=format("",w=nchar(x));write(m,"",x,,"")` is 10 bytes fewer by using negative indexing and replacing `n=x,s=''` with `x,,''`

https://tio.run/nexus/r#DYpBCsAgDAT/4imBCPVs85LSg0hLRbSQCub3NgwszDJL@cupA8bGLQ0pCkqG@VF37zMEE6on369YAM7R5J6fJKCIcUoZFzSyW8kWV9jWDw

Comment: @Giuseppe And now for something completely unreadable... [save one more byte.](https://tio.run/##HYpBCoAwDMD@0lMLLbh7fYmnMRSHOKEO1t/X4SUkEIsYVvuOsKkA3rlbdXSVt@SGxM5OfKlIwfQrH4/NCwF4rK2c2dCJiGc7T1KkJT4)

Comment: `write("[<-"(matrix(x<-scan(),x,x),k<--c(1,x),k,gsub("."," ",x)),1,x,,"")` for 72 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 21 bytes

*Uses language features newer than the question, which is allowed per current policy; if the wording of the question is interpreted to override said policy, see 25-byte answer below.*

```
Yq{MN++g%y>1?sMyy}MCy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/srDa109bO1210s7Qvti3srLW17ny/39Dg/@6OQA)

Thanks to Luis Mendo's [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73649/16766) for the `(a+1)%n<2` trick.

#### Explanation

`Yq` reads a line from stdin and yanks it into `y`. Then:

```
{              }MCy  Map this function to each coordinate pair in a y-by-y grid
                     (Inside the function, the list of both coords is g)
   ++g                Increment both coordinates
      %y              Take them mod y
 MN     >1?           Test whether the min of the resulting list is 2 or greater
           sMy         If so, it's in the center; use len(y) spaces
              y        If not, it's an edge; use the number y
                     Print result with newlines between rows (implicit, -l flag)
```

---

Original 2016 answer, **25 bytes** (plus `-l` flag):

```
Yq{MN++*a%y<2?ysX#y}MMCGy
```

Changelog:

- `MC` was added more recently; at the time, I used `MMCG` (map-map + coordinate-grid).
- There was a bug in the current interpreter that prevented using `++` on lists, so I had to do `++*` (apply `++` to each element) instead.
- `M`ap has been extended: now `<string1> M <string2>` returns a list of `len(<string2>)` copies of `<string1>`; at the time, I used `sX#y`, string-repeating space by `len(y)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```
J*K`QQI>Q1JV-Q2++Q*d-lJ*2lKQ;J
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%2aK%60QQI%3EQ1JV-Q2%2B%2BQ%2ad-lJ%2a2lKQ%3BJ&input=5&debug=0)

```
J*K`QQ                          set K to repr(input); that is, stringified
                                  set J to K repeated (input) times
      I>Q1                  ;   if input is greater than 1...
          J                     output J (stringified input times input)
           V-Q2                 do this (input - 2) times...
               ++               output the following on one line:
                 Q              the input number
                  *d-lJ*2lK     n spaces, where n = len(J) - 2*len(K)
                           Q    the input number again
                            ;   break out of everything
                             J  output J (str(input)*input) one last time,
                                  regardless of whether input > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 90

Again, I'm pretty sure this will be greatly golfable by the experts:

```
.+
$&$&$*:$&$*;
+`(\d+:):
$1$1
+`([\d+:]+;);
$1$1
T`d` `(?<=;\d+:)[^;]+(?=:\d+:;\d)
:

;
¶
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCYkJiQqOiQmJCo7CitgKFxkKzopOgokMSQxCitgKFtcZCs6XSs7KTsKJDEkMQpUYGRgIGAoPzw9O1xkKzopW147XSsoPz06XGQrOjtcZCkKOgoKOwrCtg&input=MjM)

Comment: I posted a [Retina answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73717/7311) too, but it isn't much smaller. (Can you use `¶` instead of `;` to get rid of the last stage?)

Comment: @randomra Well 80 < 90 so no argument from me :)

Comment: And if you use the pilcrow `[^¶]+` is handily `.+`.

Answer (score 2):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/tree/12c0a12837b2ff44733cf0d401da725572dd31d9), 33 bytes (noncompetitive)

```
QD`i*Djli2*lR-k*iRi]3J"bR+2Q-*jR+
```

Explanation:

```
                                  - autoassign Q = eval_or_not(input())
QD`i*                             - Get the input multiplied by itself
Q                                 - [Q]
 D                                - [Q, Q]
  `                               - [repr(Q), Q]
   i                              - i = stack[0]
    *                             - [stack[0]*stack[1]]

     Djli2*lR-                    - Get number of spaces
     D                            - [^,^]
      j                           - j = stack[0]
       l                          - len(stack[0])
        i2*                       - i*2
           l                      - len(stack[0])
            R                     - rotate_2()
             -                    - stack[0]-stack[1]

              k*iRi               - Get middle line
              k*                  - " "*^
                iRi               - [i,^,i]
                             
                   ]3J"bR+        - Join middle line together
                   ]3             - list(stack[:3])
                     J"           - "".join(stack[0])
                       bR+        - ^+"\n"

                          2Q-     - Get middle lines
                          2Q-*    - Q-2

                              jR+ - Add end line
                              jR+ - ^+j
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, 28 bytes

Grr, can’t tell if Jelly is bad at strings, or if I’m bad at Jelly.

```
ŒṘ©L⁶xWẋWẋ$®W¤1¦€U'Z$$4¡j⁷ȯ⁷
```

[Try it online.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLhuZjCqUzigbZ4V-G6i1fhuoskwq5XwqQxwqbigqxVJ1okJDTCoWrigbfIr-KBtw&input=&args=MTI)

Comment: I've been trying to adapt [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71602/21487) for an answer, but without much luck :/

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 27 bytes

```
ri:X,_ff{a+[0X(]&XXs,S*?}N*
```

Thanks to @MartinBüttner for suggesting `ff`. The `a+[0X(]&` is pretty fishy, but oh well.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%3AX%2C_ff%7Ba%2B%5B0X%28%5D%26XXs%2CS*%3F%7DN*&input=10)

```
ri:X              Read input integer and save as variable X
,_                Range, i.e. [0 1 ... X-1] and make a copy
ff{...}           Map with extra parameter, twice. This is like doing a Cartesian product
                  between two 1D arrays, but we get a nice X by X array at the end

                  For each coordinate pair,
a+                Put the two coordinates into an array
[0X(]&            Set intersection with the array [0 X-1]
X                 Push X
Xs,S*             Push a number of spaces equal to the length of X
?                 Ternary: choose one of the previous two depending on the set intersection

N*                Join X by X array with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 78 bytes

```
i x=unlines$take x$1#s:3#[s++(3#s>>" ")++s]++[1#s]where s=show x;z#s=[z..x]>>s
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStr $ i 4
4444
4  4
4  4
4444
```

The function `>>` comes in handy: `<list> >> <string>` makes `length <list>` copies of `<string>`, e.g. top and bottom lines for `x=10` are `[1..10] >> "10"` -> `"10101010101010101010"`.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwAER3vuLSMLRpIYIySKBfoJNj7dBEEoxQoa2RwX@voMPdveVeb/yjG4YYZ9iPazK1z3OrhW8y3z/fsC0t6rJ2UnpWU@o5pxtLSUAY5541qVtX9Z25patCx9D5gBajmUCvSyZnLOAcihDNoEqBvcBBoBI4ChS7NZVOktHc7f91Bv319AqX4E6WYTMm8Qs "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @MaxYekhlakov: Thanks, but unfortunately your version doesn't work for `1` which shout output a single `1`. Also, you return a list of strings, whereas the challenge asks for a single string. We had much stricter IO rules back in the days, flexible IO rules are a more recent thing.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 72 bytes

```
$_=($.=pop)-2;say for($.x$.,($..($.x$_)=~s/./ /rg.$.)x$_,$.x$.)[0..$.-1]
```

Relies on modern Perl features :

> **say** 'something'

is automatically available since Perl 5.10 (simply use v5.10 or later).

> str_expr =~ s/.../.../**r**

happily accepts to work on a rvalue (an str_expr not necessarily reduced to a scalar variable) to yield a **r**esult (the '**r**' option at the end of the regex) without altering the initial str_expr.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 151 bytes

```
function s($n){for($r=0;$r<$n;$r++){for($c=0;$c<$n;$c++){if($r*$c&&$r!=$n-1&&$c!=$n-1){for($d=0;$d<=log10($n);$d++){echo' ';}}else{echo$n;}}echo"\n";}}
```

Absolute mess, need more time to optimize.  `s(Number)` gives you the output.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, <del>108</del> <del>96</del> 148 bytes

```
a=input()
b=c=int(a)-2 if a!="1" else 0
print(a*int(a))
while b:print(a+" "*int(len(a))*c+a);b-=1
if a!="1":print(a*int(a))
```

Ungolfed/explained:

```
number = input() # Gets a number as input
iterator = var = int(number) - 2 if number != "1" else 0 # Assigns two variables, one of them an iterator, to the number minus 2 (the amount of middle rows in the square) if the number isn't 1. If it is, it sets the vars to 0 so the while doesn't trigger.
print(number * int(number)) # Prints the top row of the square.
while iterator != 0: # Loops for the middle rows
    print(number + " " * int(len(number)) * var + number) # Prints the number, then as many spaces as needed, and the number.
    iterator -= 1 # De-increments the iterator.
if number != 1: # Makes sure the number isn't 1, because 1 should return 1.
    print(a * int(a)) # Same as the first row, it prints the bottom row.
```

As this is my first [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) answer, some constructive criticism and/or suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Use single spaces for indentation to shave off some bytes. In fact, your entire loop can be inlined: `while b!=0:print(a+" "*int(len(a))*c+1);b-=1`. Furthermore, `while b:` is equivalent to `while b!=0`, so that's 3 more bytes gone.

Comment: Bugfix: input 1 now prints 1, not infiniteloop (my browser really gave me some grief). This now takes tons more bytes tho.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8, 280 bytes

```java
interface A{static<T>void p(T o){System.out.print(o);}static void main(String[]a){long n=new Long(a[0]),l=a[0].length();for(long i=0;i<n;i++,p(a[0]));p("\n"+(n>1?a[0]:""));for(long j=2;j<n;j++,p(a[0])){for(long i=l*2;i<n*l;i++,p(' '));p(a[0]+"\n");}for(long i=1;i<n;i++)p(a[0]);}}
```

It's only about 10 times as long as the shortest answers, which is really good for Java!

Example run:

```
$ java A 10
10101010101010101010
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10101010101010101010
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, <strike>141</strike> 137 bytes

Abused some formatting stuff, otherwise this would've been a lot longer.

```rust
|i|{let f=||{for _ in 0..i{print!("{}",i)}println!("")};f();if i>1{for _ in 0..i-2{println!("{}{0:1$}",i,i.to_string().len()*(i-1))}f()}}
```

Unpacked:

```rust
|i| {
    let f = || {
        for _ in 0..i {
            print!("{}",i)
        }
        println!("")
    };

    f();

    if i>1 {
        for _ in 0..i-2 {
            println!("{}{0:1$}",i,i.to_string().len()*(i-1))
        }
        f()
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ffe943a1b9ae16ffbd9cbc295cd3871&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: This doesn't work when I try it [here](http://play.rust-lang.org).  How can I test this?

Comment: [Here's a playground link so you can test it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d773a0a38e718b63e2f40860e731e2f1&version=stable&backtrace=0), I used a closure so you have assign that to a variable first then call it.

Comment: Oh cool.  Don't really know rust, but great answer!

Comment: Nice answer, you can try putting the variable directly inside the string `println!("{i}")` . Also try using clippy in rust playground(Tools>Clippy).

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>98</s> <s>96</s> <s>95</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s> 75 bytes

```powershell
param($n)($l="$n"*$n)
if(($m=$n-2)-ge0){,"$n$(' '*"$n".Length*$m)$n"*$m
$l}
```

Ungolfed and explained test script:

```powershell
$f = {

    param($n)
    ($l="$n"*$n)                #   let $l is a string contains N only and return this value as a first line
    $m=$n-2
    if($m-ge0){                 # if(N>1)
        $s=' '*"$n".Length*$m   #   let $s is spaces inside repeated (length of string represented of n * m)
        ,"$n$s$n"*$m            #   return $m strings contains: N, spaces and N
        $l                      #   retrun the first line again
    }

}

&$f 1
&$f 2
&$f 3
&$f 4
&$f 10
```

Output:

```powershell
1
22
22
333
3 3
333
4444
4  4
4  4
4444
10101010101010101010
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10                10
10101010101010101010
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 19 bytes

```
░*k┴╜o\⌡{khí **k++p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RtIla2Y@mbHk0dU5@zKOehdXZGYfXKmhpZWtrF/z/b8BlyGXEZcxlwmXKZQjkmHKZGvwHAA)

### Explanation

This was a fun challenge. Disclaimer: this language is younger than the challenge itself, but the methods used for this answer are not designed for this challenge in particular. I realised that I can save a byte for the 1-case, and by reducing the number of print statements.

```
░                     convert implicit input to string
 *                    pop a, b : push(a*b)
  k                   read integer from input
   ┴                  check if equal to 1
    ╜                 else without if
     o                print TOS without popping (handles the 1-case)
      \               swap top elements
       ⌡              decrement twice
        {             start block or arbitrary length
         k            read integer from input
          h           length of array/string without popping
           í          get total number of iterations of for loop
                      space character
             *        pop a, b : push(a*b)
              *       pop a, b : push(a*b) (this results in (n-2)*numdigits(n)*" ")
               k      read integer from input
                +     pop a, b : push(a+b)
                 +    pop a, b : push(a+b)
                  p   print with newline
```

Comment: @JoKing that added two bytes. I wanted to be able to use the "make each list element equal in length" operator, but I couldn't get it working as I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
ẋṅ,⇩(L⁰‹*$S↲₴,)ċ[ẋṅ,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuovhuYUs4oepKEzigbDigLkqJFPihrLigrQsKcSLW+G6i+G5hSwiLCIiLCIxMCJd)

### How?

```
ẋṅ,⇩(L⁰‹*$S↲₴,)ċ[ẋṅ,
ẋ                    # Repeat the (implicit) input the (implicit) input number of times (returns a list)
 ṅ                   # Join by nothing
  ,                  # Print with trailing newline
   ⇩(                # Loop (implicit) input minus 2 times:
     L               #  Get the length of the (implicit) input
      ⁰‹             #  Push the input minus 1
        *            #  Multiply the length by that
         $           #  Swap to make (implicit) input at top
          S          #  Convert the input to a string
           ↲         #  Pad the stringified input with leading spaces until its length is len(input) * (input - 1) calculated earlier
            ₴        #  Print this without a trailing newline
             ,       #  Print the (implicit) input with trailing newline
              )      # Close loop
               ċ[    # If the (implicit) input is not one:
                 ẋ   #  Repeat the (implicit) input the (implicit) input amount of times
                  ṅ  #  Join by nothing to make it a string
                   , #  Print with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 27 bytes

```
jsMmm?sqM*,dk,0tQ`Q*\ l`QQQ
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jsMmm%3FsqM%2a%2Cdk%2C0tQ%60Q%2a%5C+l%60QQQ&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A10&debug=1).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>34</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

Code:

```
F¹}JDU,¹!#¹DÍF¹gFð}}¹J¹ÍF=}X,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=RsK5fUpEVSzCuSEjwrlEw41GwrlnRsOwfX3CuUrCucONRj19WCw&input=MTA)

I didn't have some kind of fancy string multiplication function, but here is the submission *with* the function. It's something I added after the challenge and is therefore non-competing:

**26 bytes:**

Code:

```
D×DU,¹¹Í¹g*ð×¹J¹ÍF=}¹1›iX,
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 70 characters

```python
def p(i):
 k=`i`;j=i-2;h=k*i;print h+'\n'+(k+' '*j*len(k)+k+'\n')*j+h
```

Comment: Doesn't work for i=1.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 79 bytes

```
->n{s=n.to_s
puts s*n
$><<(s+" "*s.size*(a=n-2)+s+$/)*a if n>2
$><<s*n if n>1}
```

Some cases print a trailing line after the last line and some do not, but the question does not disallow this.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 112 <s>114</s> <s>120</s> bytes

```
<?php $z=$j=$argv[1];while($j){$i=(--$j&&$i)?$z.str_pad('',strlen($z)*($z-2)).$z:str_repeat($z,$z);echo"$i\n";}
```

Command line usage: `php scriptname.php [n]`

[ideone demo](https://ideone.com/lbsfjv)

This golf uses `str_repeat` for the first and last row and `str_pad` for the rows in between.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 41 bytes

```
{1≥⍵:⍵⍴⍵⋄(' '≠⍕⍵/⍵)/⍕⍵⍪⍨⍵⍪⍵,⍵,⍨''⍴⍨2/⍵-2}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 73 characters

```
def l(i):s=`i`;n='\n';l=i-2;b=s*i+n;print b+(s+' '*l*len(s)+s+n)*l+b*(i>1)
```

Comment: I believe your `n='\n';` optimization is costing you one character, not saving any.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, <strike>101</strike> 135 bytes:

(*+34 since apparently an input of 1 should just output 1 and an input of 0 should output nothing*)

```
def y(g):g=str(g);i=len(g);[print(g*(int(g))+('\n'+g+' '*((int(g)*i)-(i*2))+g)*(int(g)-2)+'\n'+g*int(g))if int(g)>1 else print(g*int(g))]
```

Prints out all the correct values for any integer input, whether in string form or not.

**Sample Inputs and Outputs:**

```
Input: y(10)

Output:

    10101010101010101010
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10                10
    10101010101010101010

Input: y(1)

Output:

    1

Input: y(2)

Output:

    22
    22

Input: y(4)

Output: 

    4444
    4  4
    4  4
    4444
```

However, for triple digit numbers, it was just too big to fit on my monitor, so I hope that comes out correct if someone else tries it. I suspect it should since all 1 and 2 digit numbers come out correctly.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 75 characters

```
def q(n):s=str(n);m=n-2;print(s*n,*[s+" "*len(s)*m+s]*m,s*n*(n>1),sep="\n")
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. This is a great first answer, however it would be even better if you added a code explanation and breakdown as well.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoQgEEbhqxiqmRELsdPgRdRuMWsiv@hgsadntXvJl5d@@XugK@UT1uokcK9e8/XEED0aN6RrQyYVWJm0NpWRPYCUJda6SLSPCGFs2WpI3swwXE56nw3pzsTMxXV/ "Python 3 – Try It Online") Also, as a full program this is [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##HckxDoAgDEDRnVOYTrTgIMx4EXUk0URqY3Hw9Ejc/s@Tt@4Xx9Y0HSxPtWi4V7WKpiQeg5H7X2JPizoYgM7Mnak43aj4LmR5ntBrlgQrA7YW4gc "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 86 Bytes

```php
for(;$i<$a=$argn;)echo str_pad($a>1?$a:"",($a-1)*strlen($a),$i++&&$i<$a?" ":$a)."$a
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HYtLCoAgFEXnriIeD8m0oKCJVi4lHv0hVKz9mzQ791zOYMMZGFI83Nj1Ju0@lgavAWn8pRHbcvrieeMcaC2RptYiaQCVuW5FlZ97c3kIhZeUnP@xhQJ0dg0gMTApfQ)

Answer (score 1):

## JS to ES6 compatibilized, <s>136</s> 76 B

```
function x(a){var c='';function Q(){for(var b=0;b<a;++b)c+=a}Q();c+='\n';
for(b=2;b<a;++b){c+=a;for(let A=2;A<a;++a)c+=' ';c+=a+'\n'}Q()}
```

Works way smaller:

```
x=(a,c)=>{Q=(í,k)=>{for(;í<a;++í)c+=k}Q(0,a);c+='\n';Q(2,a+Q(2,' ')+a+'\n')}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2,96 bytes**

```
s=raw_input()
n=int(s)
for i in range(n):
 if 0<i<n-1:print s+' '*(n-2)*len(s)+s
 else:print s*n
```

**Python 3,94 bytes**

```
s=input()
n=int(s)
for i in range(n):
 if 0<i<n-1:print(s+' '*(n-2)*len(s)+s)
 else:print(s*n)
```

Comment: You accidentally left a space after the assignment to `n` in both answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
N=input()
n=int(N)
m=n-2
b=N*n+"\n"
print(b+(N+" "*len(N)*m+N+"\n")*m+b*(n>1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/3882M6@gtERDkysPyCrR8NPkyrXN0zXiSrL108rTVorJU@IqKALJJGlr@GkrKShp5aTmAZVp5Wr7gaVBrCQtjTw7Q03N//9NAQ)

I went back and forth over multiple approaches to this (even using `exec()` at one point, then ditching it because it was unnecessary), but I figured out that this is the shortest Python 3 approach.

Comment: As a subroutine this is [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYpBDkAwFAWvIl3938YCO00d4Z/AqkFIeIpaOH2p3UxmwhPnHU1KwzgVB4FbcVc8P7CbQ1lb70TDqB7KhnNBJG9IjCqUXkeQsN6M/DmT14SuYk4H5XVBuCPx53XzAg "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
×,<GgIÍ*ú«,}≠i×,
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8HQdG/d0z8O9Wod3HVqtU/uoc0EmUOz/f0MDAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VQ@amrRc/l/eLqOjXt65eFercO7Dq3WqX3UuSATKPa/9tA2e82Y/9EGOoY6RjrGOiY6pjqWOoYGOkbGsQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
×          # Repeat the (implicit) input the (implicit) input amount of times as string
 ,         # Pop and print this string with trailing newline
<G         # Loop the (implicit) input-2 amount of times:
  g        #  Get the length of the (implicit) input
   IÍ      #  Push the input-2
     *     #  Multiply it by the length
      ú    #  Pad the (implicit) input with that many leading spaces
       «   #  Append it to the (implicit) input
        ,  #  Pop and print it with trailing newline
 }         # Close the loop
  ≠i       # If the (implicit) input is NOT 1:
    ×      #  Repeat the (implicit) input the (implicit) input amount of times as string
     ,     #  Pop and print this string with trailing newline
```

I don't think I've ever used the fact that input can be implicitly as many times in a single program as this one. xD

Answer (score 1):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 42 bytes

```
(($~1){$~1})((
$2 {#2}{$2-2}$2){$2-2}
$1!)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72qKDU9NS-1KLEkdcGCpaUlaboWN7U0NFTqDDWrgUStpoYGl4qRQrWyUW21ipGuUa2KkSaEwaViqKgJ0QHVuCxaychYKRbKAwA)

For clarity, space is replaced with `_` and newline is replaced with `¶`:

```
(                    # Capture the first line as $1, for reuse as the last line.
    ($~1){$~1}       # Repeat N in decimal, N times. Capture N in $2 for golf,
                     # which allows referring to it as "$2" instead of "$~1" and
                     # its length as "#2" instead of "#~1".
)
(
    (
        ¶
        $2           # Output N in decimal for the left edge.
        _{#2}{$2-2}  # Output length(N)*(N-2) spaces
        $2           # Output N in decimal for the right edge.
    ){$2-2}          # Repeat the above N-2 times. This will cause a non-match
                     # if N == 1, preventing this entire block from matching,
                     # which will also prevent the top line from being repeated
                     # as the bottom line below.
    ¶
    $1               # Repeat the top line as the bottom line.
!
                     # If N == 1, the above alternative won't be able to match;
                     # do nothing here, to prevent it from triggering a top-level
                     # non-match.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica,116 bytes

```
Switch[#,0,"",1,1,_,#5<>#4[#<>#4[" ",StringLength@#*#3]<>#<>"\n",#3]<>#5&[##,#~#4~#2<>"\n"]&[ToString@#,#,#-2,Table]]&
```

Somewhat long, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, <s>106</s> <s>105</s> 115 bytes

```
SELECT RPAD(:1,(:1-1)*LENGTH(:1),DECODE(LEVEL,1,:1||'',:1,:1||'',' '))||:1 FROM DUAL WHERE:1>0 CONNECT BY:1>=LEVEL;
```

10 bytes added to manage 0

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 89 bytes

```
INPUT N$N=VAL(N$)Q=N>1FOR I=1TO N?N$*!!N*G;" "*LEN(N$*(N-Q*2))*G;N$*(Q*G+N*!G)G=I<N-1NEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 151 bytes

```
(defun c(x)(if(< x 10)1(1+(c(/ x 10)))))(lambda(a)(format t"~:[~v{~a~:*~}~&~v@{~v<~a~;~a~>~4@*~&~}~*~v@{~a~:*~}~;1~]"(= a 1)a`(,a)(- a 2)(*(c a)a)a a))
```

function for counting digits adjusted to CL from Joshua's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530112/how-to-count-number-of-digits)

#### Ungolfed

```
(defun c(x)
    (if(< x 10) 1
    (1+ (c(/ x 10))))) ;counting digits
(lambda(a)
    (format t"~:[~v{~a~:*~}~&~v@{~v<~a~;~a~>~4@*~&~}~*~v@{~a~:*~}~;1~]"(= a 1)a`(,a)(- a 2)(*(c a)a)a a))
;~[~] checks whether agument is equal 1 (if it is equal 1 then print out only "1") - without it we would print out 1\Newline 1
;first loop: ~v{~a~:*~} - printing first line of N
;second loop: uses justification "~<~>" to output enough spaces between N's on sides
;third loop: -printing last line of N
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>61</s> 58 bytes

```
;_LA|x=!A!~x=1|?A\Y=A+space$((x-2)*a)+A[x|Z=Z+A]?Z[x-2|?Y]
```

Explanation

```
;          Read A$ from the cmd line
_LA|       Take the length of A$ and assign to a
x=!A!      Cast A$ to int, assign to x
~x=1|?A    If x == 1, quit printing just the 1
\Y=A       Else, setup Y$ as the middle of the square; it starts as the literal input
  +space$( Followed by X spaces
  (x-2)*a) where X is the length of the string x the value, minus start and end
  +A       Followed by the input again
[x|        This FOR loop creates the top row
Z=Z+A]     By concatenating the input x times to itself and assigning it to Z$
?Z         Print the top row
[x-2|?Y]   Print the right amount of middle rows
           And the bottom row (Z$) is implicitly printed at EOF.
```

Comment: Non-competing maybe?

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 101 bytes

```
p,n=print,io.read()d,s=#n,n:rep(n)p(s)for i=3,n do p(n..(" "):rep(d*(n-2))..n)end p(n+0>1 and s or"")
```

Alternate 102 bytes:

```
l,n="\n",io.read()d,s=#n,n:rep(n)print(s..l..(n..(" "):rep(d*(n-2))..n..l):rep(n-2)..(n+0>1 and s or""))
```

101 Readable:

```
p,n=print,io.read()
d,s=#n,n:rep(n)
p(s)
for i=3,n do 
  p(n..(" "):rep(d*(n-2))..n)
end 
p(n+0>1 and s or"")
```

Lua naturally has a small trick here by being able to convert a number as a string (e.g. "123") into a string or a number as needed based on context. It's not 100% intelligent though as you can see in my "ternary" statement at the end for handling the 0 and 1 cases- I had to use n+0 to coax it into a number before comparing it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 67+2=69 bytes

Requires the flags `-lp`.

```
$@=($,=$"=$_)-2;$,x=$,;s/./ /g;$"=$".$_ x$@.$".$/;$_=$,.$/.$"x$@.$,
```

Has all the length of a mainstream language, and the unreadability of a more esoteric language!

Answer (score 0):

## [WC](https://wasp-compiled.firebaseapp.com/), 146 bytes

```
;>_0|;>_0|$-;>_0|;>=_0|[<]$'[>]$--[>]$--[>];>_0|$''_0|!$?#@3|//#;>(?[>]$-!!_0|;>@5|$''[<<<<]!!$?!$[>>>>>>];<?[>]##@3|/#)?##@10|[>>>>>]*$#?[>>>>]!$
```

[Try it online!](https://wasp-compiled.firebaseapp.com/?;%3E_0|;%3E_0|$-;%3E_0|;%3E=_0|[%3C]$%27[%3E]$--[%3E]$--[%3E];%3E_0|$%27%27_0|!$?#@3|//#;>(?[>]$-!!_0|;>@5|$''[<<<<]!!$?!$[>>>>>>];<?[>]##@3|/#)?##@10|[>>>>>]*$#?[>>>>]!$&16)

Ungolfed/commented:

```
;>_0|;>_0|       var n, var c
$-               decrement c
;>_0|;>=_0|      var i, var len = length(X)
[<]              move to i
$'[>]            multply i by len
$--[>]$--[>]     i -= len (x2)
;>_0|$''_0|      var full = X repeated X times
!$               print full
?                reset index
#@3|             if n == 0
  //             terminate
#                end if
;>(              new function
  ?[>]           set index to 1
  $-!!_0|        decrement c and print it
  ;>@5|          var spaces
  $''[<<<<]      repeat i times
  !!$            print spaces
  ?              reset index
  !$             print n
  [>>>>>>]       move to spaces
  ;<             delete spaces var
  ?[>]           set index to 1
  ##@3|          if c != 0
    /            restart context (this function)
  #              end if
)                end function
?                reset index
##@10|           if n != 2 (10th global)
  [>>>>>]        set index to 5
  *$             call the function
#                end if
?[>>>>]          set index to 4
!$                print full
```

Comment: When you compile Wasp, it becomes the Water Closet

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 69 chars, 138 bytes

```
{⍵≤1:⍕⍳⍵⋄f←{⊂∊⍺/⊂⍕⍵}⋄y←((⍴⊃x←f⍨⍵)-2×⍴r←⍕⍵)f' '⋄⊃x,((⊂∊r,y,r)/⍨⍵-2),x}
```

test:

```
  g←{⍵≤1:⍕⍳⍵⋄f←{⊂∊⍺/⊂⍕⍵}⋄y←((⍴⊃x←f⍨⍵)-2×⍴r←⍕⍵)f' '⋄⊃x,((⊂∊r,y,r)/⍨⍵-2),x}
  ⎕fmt   g¨0 1 2 3 11  
┌5──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌0┐ ┌1┐ ┌2─┐ ┌3──┐ ┌22────────────────────┐│
││ │ │1│ 222│ 3333│ 11111111111111111111111││
│└¯┘ └─┘ │22│ │3 3│ 111                  11││
│        └──┘ │333│ │11                  11││
│             └───┘ │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │11                  11││
│                   │1111111111111111111111││
│                   └──────────────────────┘2
└∊──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
*zKszVSJ-K2p+z*J*lzdz)I>K1*zK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X6vKu7gqLNhL19uoQLtKy0srpyqlStPTztsQKPP/v6EBAA)

Properly handles "1" case, even if it cost me 3 more characters to do so. Still new to Pyth, and there's some interesting stuff happening with that Pyth answer that uses all the joins.

```
*zKsz        #input auto-assigned to z as string, assign K to int(z), and print z*K
VSJ-K2       #set J to K-2, for N in range J
p+z*J*lzdz   #print with no newline: z + (" " * len(z)) * (K - 2), print z
)I>K1*zK     #close for loop and print z*K if K greater than 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 146 bytes

```cs
a=>{string b=a.ToString(),s="";for(int i=0,j,k;++i<=a;s+="\n")for(j=0;++j<=a;)if(i>1&i<a&j>1&j<a)for(k=0;k++<b.Length;)s+=" ";else s+=b;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU5Na4QwED3XXzF4WBK04rbHGKEUCoXtpVvopZfojttRm0AmLhTxt9u4Zecy876G1/J96zyuE5M9w/GXA/4oaEfDDE8wJxxMoBZeJttWZEMOHHx01tCBXo2u538MjTbFhztegZA56zRVnfMiZoB0mff5oLKMKm0UZzr9sqnc5F6Xke43WlInqN7vqDK7Pu6@MlfLEC1DllVNcUB7Dt9Kbg8gVTgyQrwb5TFM3gKrZVW3xhdHJ3gzZIWck7tnZ9mNWHx6Cig6EfEFfYiVX214fBA3/R3N6UAWhYyjkmVZ9@Uf)

Ungolfed:

```cs
a => {
    string b = a.ToString(), s = "";            // initialize b (saves 4 bytes) and s (return variable)
    for(int i = 0, j, k; ++i <= a; s += "\n")   // for each row of the square
        for(j = 0; ++j <= a;)                       // for each column of the square
            if(i > 1 & i < a & j > 1 & j < a)           // if not an edge of the square
                for(k = 0; k++ < b.Length;)                 // for each digit in a
                    s += " ";                                   // add a space
            else                                        // if an edge of the square
                s += b;                                     // add the input num
    return s;                                   // output the full string
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 bytes

```
_hUçU)z3
NgV gV gV gV
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Cl9oVedVKXozCk5nViBnViBnViBnVg==&input=NQotUQ==)

More competitive than I expected, though I wouldn't be surprised if Charcoal or something has a really short answer that just hasn't been found yet.

Explanation:

```
                :Empty line preserves the input as U

_hUçU)z3        :Declare a function V taking an argument Z:
_h   )          : Set the first line of Z to
    U           :  U as a string
  Uç            :  Repeated U times
      z3        : Rotate Z 90 degrees counterclockwise

NgV gV gV gV    :Main program
N               : Start with an arbitrary array (in this case [U])
 gV gV gV gV    : Apply V 4 times
```

It's necessary to rotate counterclockwise in `V` because a single-line array always ends up left-aligned when rotated, making clockwise rotations take an extra `gV`. The 1 extra byte for `z3` instead of `z` was better.

Answer (score 0):

## Japt `-R`, 18 bytes

```
îU
U+ÕÅ+UÔÅ Õ·hJUw
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=7lUKVSvVxStV1MUg1bdoSlV3&input=MwoKLVI=)

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 264 bytes

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&set o=&set m=
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do set o=!o!%1&if %%i gtr 2 set m=!m!%1
if %1 gtr 0 echo %o%&if %1 gtr 2 (for /l %%i in (0,1,9)do set m=!m:%%i= !
set/an=%1-2
for /l %%i in (1,1,!n!)do echo %1!m!%1)
if %1 gtr 1 echo %o%
```

Only works for numbers up to 2029 because of the length limitations of `echo`.