# Code golf ABC's: The ASCII Box Challenge

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid

Given two positive integers, 'a' and 'b', output an ascii-art "box" that is *a* characters wide and *b* characters tall. For example, with '4' and '6':

```
****
*  *
*  *
*  *
*  *
****
```

Simple right? Here's the twist: The border of the box must be the characters of "a" and "b" alternating. This starts at the top left corner, and continues in a clockwise spiral. For example, the previous example with 4 and 6 should be

```
4646
6  4
4  6
6  4
4  6
6464
```

A and B *may* be two-digit numbers. For example, the inputs "10" and "3" should output this:

```
1031031031
1        0
3013013013
```

In order to keep the output relatively small, you do not have to support three or more digit numbers. Also, since inputs are restricted to *positive* integers, '0' is an invalid input, which you do not have to handle.

Here are some more test cases:

```
Input: (3, 5)
Output:

353
5 5
3 3
5 5
353

Input: (1, 1)
Output:

1

Input: (4, 4)
Output:

4444
4  4
4  4
4444

Input: (27, 1)
Output:

271271271271271271271271271

Input: (1, 17)
Output:

1
1
7
1
1
7
1
1
7
1
1
7
1
1
7
1
1

Input: (12, 34):
Output:

123412341234
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
4          1
3          2
2          3
1          4
432143214321
```

You may take input and output in any reasonable format, and standard loopholes are banned. Since this is code-golf, the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73642/31716)

Comment: Must I start the pattern from the top left hand corner clockwise?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, that is necessary.

Comment: If `a` is 1 is it the left wall or the right wall?

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm not sure if it makes any difference. Either way, I added a test case with `a = 1`

Comment: do i have to print the box?

Comment: Isn't the first example wrong? (3,5) should be 3 wide and 5 tall

Comment: @Brian Yes, you're right. Sorry about that, fixed now.

Comment: Is a leading newline ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>65</s> 51 bytes

```
juXGhHX@GhHeH@jkQ~hZ{s[+L]0UhQ+R]thQUeQ+L]teQ_UhQ+R]0_UeQ)m*;hQeQ
AQjuXGhHX@GhHeH@jkQ~hZ{s[,L0G,RtGH_,LtHG_,R0H)m*;GH
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AQjuXGhHX%40GhHeH%40jkQ~hZ%7Bs%5B%2CL0G%2CRtGH_%2CLtHG_%2CR0H%29m%2a%3BGH&input=10%2C3&debug=0)

Answer (score 4):

### C#, 301 bytes

I'm sure there is a lot more golfing that can be done here but I'm just happy I got a solution that worked.

I found a bug where the bottom line was in the wrong order, damnit!

```
a=>b=>{var s=new string[b];int i=4,c=b-2,k=a;var t="";for(;i++<2*(a+b);)t+=t.EndsWith(a+"")?b:a;s[0]=t.Substring(0,a);if(b>2){for(i=0;++i<b-1;)s[i]=(a<2?t.Substring(1,c):t.Substring(2*a+c))[c-i]+(a>1?new string(' ',a-2)+t.Substring(a,c)[i-1]:"");for(;--k>=0;)s[b-1]+=t.Substring(a+c,a)[k];}return s;};
```

Old version: 280 bytes

```
a=>b=>{var s=new string[b];int i=4,c=b-2;var t="";for(;i++<2*(a+b);)t+=t.EndsWith(a+"")?b:a;s[0]=t.Substring(0,a);if(b>2){for(i=0;++i<b-1;)s[i]=(a<2?t.Substring(1,c):t.Substring(2*a+c))[c-i]+(a>1?new string(' ',a-2)+t.Substring(a,c)[i-1]:"");s[b-1]=t.Substring(a+c,a);}return s;};
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 199 bytes

```python
w,h=input()
s=(`w`+`h`)*w*h
r=[s[:w]]+[[" "for i in[0]*w]for j in[0]*(h-2)]+[s[w+h-2:2*w+h-2][::-1]]*(h>1)
for y in range(1,h-1):r[y][w-1],r[y][0]=s[w+y-1],s[w+h+w-2-y]
print"\n".join(map("".join,r))
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <del>213</del> <del>212</del> 202

```
c=>a=>{for(a=$=a,c=_=c,l=c*a*2,b=0,s=Array(l+1).join(c+""+a),O=W=s.substr(0,a),W=W.substr(0,a-2).replace(/./g," ");--_;)O+="\n"+s[l-c+_]+W+s[$++];return O+"\n"+[...s.substr(l-a-c+1,a)].reverse().join``}
```

Surely has room for improvement.

**Edit:** Saved a byte thanks to TheLethalCoder

Comment: I think `\`${c}${a}\`.repeat(l+1)` might save you a byte.

Comment: Oh, and isn't' `W=W.substr(0,a-2).replace(/./g," ")` the same as `W=" ".repeat(a-2)`? (Does your code actually work for `a=1`?)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 128 bytes

```
->w,h{s="%d%d"%[w,h]*q=w+h;a=[s[0,w]];(h-2).times{|i|a<<(s[2*q-5-i].ljust(w-1)+s[w+i,1])[-w,w]};puts a,h>1?(s[q-2,w].reverse):p}
```

Outputs trailing newline if height is 1.

Ideone link: https://ideone.com/96WYHt

Comment: You can do `[w,h]*""` instead of `"%d%d"%[w,h]` for 4 bytes, and you don't need the parentheses around `s[q-2,w].reverse`, but then you'll need a space after the `:`, so -1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 311 bytes

```c
char s[5];sprintf(s,"%d%d",a, b);int z=strlen(s);int i=0;while(i<a){printf("%c",s[i++%z]);}if(b>2){i=1;while(i<b-1){char r=s[(a+i-1)%z];char l=s[(2*a+2*b-i-4)%z];if(a>1){printf("\n%c%*c",l,a-1,r);}else{printf("\n%c",l);}i++;}}printf("\n");if(b>1){i=0;while(i<a){printf("%c",s[(2*a+b-i-3)%z]);i++;}printf("\n");}
```

Uses automatically included libraries `stdio.h` and `string.h`.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 171 bytes

```
(w,h)=>[...Array(h)].map((_,i)=>i?++i<h?(w>1?s[p+p+1-i]+` `.repeat(w-2):``)+s[w+i-2]:[...s.substr(p,w)].reverse().join``:s.slice(0,w),s=`${w}${h}`.repeat(p=w+h-2)).join`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Creates a repeated digit string, then decides what to concatenate based on which row we're on; top row is just the initial slice of the repeated digit string, bottom row (if any) is a reversed slice from the middle of the string, while intervening rows are built up using characters taken from other parts of the string.

Comment: You can use currying by changing `(w,h)=>` to `w=>h=>` to save a byte

Answer (score 0):

## TSQL, 291 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @ INT=5,@2 INT=4

,@t INT,@z varchar(max)SELECT @t=iif(@*@2=1,1,(@+@2)*2-4),@z=left(replicate(concat(@,@2),99),@t)v:PRINT iif(len(@z)=@t,left(@z,@),iif(len(@z)>@,right(@z,1)+isnull(space(@-2)+left(@z,1),''),reverse(@z)))SET @z=iif(len(@z)=@t,stuff(@z,1,@,''),substring(@z,2,abs(len(@z)-2)))IF @<=len(@z)goto v
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @ INT=5,@2 INT=4

,@t INT,@z varchar(max)
SELECT @t=iif(@*@2=1,1,(@+@2)*2-4),@z=left(replicate(concat(@,@2),99),@t)

v:
  PRINT
    iif(len(@z)=@t,left(@z,@),iif(len(@z)>@,right(@z,1)
      +isnull(space(@-2)+left(@z,1),''),reverse(@z)))
  SET @z=iif(len(@z)=@t,stuff(@z,1,@,''),substring(@z,2,abs(len(@z)-2)))
IF @<=len(@z)goto v
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/526524/code-golf-abcs-the-ascii-box-challenge)**

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>155</s> 148 bytes

Golfed off 7 more bytes:

```
p=print
def f(w,h):
 s=((str(w)+str(h))*w*h)[:2*w+2*h-4or 1];p(s[:w])
 for i in range(h-2):p(['',s[-i-1]][w>1]+' '*(w-2)+s[w+i])
 p(s[1-h:1-h-w:-1])
```

Substituted `2*w+2*h-4or 1` for `max(1,2*w+2*h-4)` and 
`['',s[-i-1]][w>1]` for `(s[-i-1]if w>1else'')`.

Prior version:

```
p=print
def f(w,h):
 s=((str(w)+str(h))*w*h)[:max(1,2*w+2*h-4)];p(s[:w])
 for i in range(h-2):p((s[-i-1]if w>1else'')+' '*(w-2)+s[w+i])
 p(s[1-h:1-h-w:-1])
```