# Form tiles in a rectangular ring

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Given the input `tilesX` and `tilesY` create a method that would make a rectangular ring from the tiles.

The function must order the tiles in a ring like this:

[image]

- `tilesX` and `tilesY` are always positive integer values, cannot be 0
- `tilesX` and `tilesY` are not always equal, expect values like: `2x5`, `6x3` etc.
- Checking for invalid input is not necessary
- You can use any way to display the tiles, including 2d arrays, ASCII art or printed text.
- There's no strict way how the input is passed as long as it's two integers.
- Cannot be a line, drawing a rectangle size of `tilesX` and `tilesY` pixels is not valid
- The shortest code wins

Comment: Could you give examples of input/output ?

Comment: Can we use a full program as well as a function?

Comment: @FliiFe Input is two integers ( cannot be negative or null ), output is a printed image like in the image attached.

Comment: Can the output be a 2D array?

Comment: @muddyfish I would very much prefer the solution to be mathematical and not a part of some API.

Comment: @Doorknob sure, that's totally valid

Comment: _You can use any way to display the tiles_ You should clarify this. Can it be ASCII art? Any characters?

Comment: @LuisMendo yes, you can use ASCII art or any characters if you want to display it in the output window/console. I'll update the question.

Comment: Sorry for the bombardment, but some clarifying questions, part 1: 1) Is the expected output an image (e.g. JPG/PNG/displayed to screen) or ASCII-art? You seem to mention both in the comments, 2) Is the "4x4" or similar text part of the output? 3) Any rules on spacing between the tiles?

Comment: @Sp3000 no rule how to display the image, it can be text ( but I thought Mathematica golfers might want to output an image and not text ). No rule on how to pass the input, so long as the input are two integers. No rule for spacing the tiles. Each tile can be viewed as a pixel.

Comment: In that case I'd recommend giving example outputs for ASCII art as well so people know what's allowed (allowing both image and ASCII output's a bit weird, but your choice I guess). I'd also suggest removing mentions of "square" if the width/height are taken as input, since that might confuse people.

Comment: Clarifications part two: 4) In the case of ASCII output, any rules on what characters are allowed to represent the tiles and the blank space in between?

Comment: I also suggest that you allow either a function or a program, as usual on this site.

Comment: @Sp3000 absolutely any characters can be used to represent the tile. There's no space between the tiles in case of ASCII/text output, the tiles must be neighboring to each other.

Comment: @CreativeMagic If the output is an array, can we use the language's default displaying of arrays, even if that means spaces between the numbers? (see my answer for example)

Comment: @LuisMendo it's allowed, but it's simply my own preference to have the logic of placing the tiles in the method, other than that it's pretty free.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73642/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71591/8478)

Comment: @CreativeMagic When you say "cannot be a line... drawing a rectangle size is not valid", do you mean that it cannot be a _thin_ line? That is, if the "line" becomes a frame one tile thick (see my answer) is it valid?

Comment: @LuisMendo your answer is valid, I just wanted to prevent a hack that would use drawing API's of some languages for example drawRect( 0, 0, tilesX, tilesY )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, 8 bytes

```
×/¨1<⊂|⍳
```

This monadic function train takes height and width as right arguments and returns a 2D array of **0**'s (border) and **1**'s (interior). Test it on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%20%u2190%20%D7/%A81%3C%u2282%7C%u2373%20%u22C4%20f%207%2013&run).

#### How it works

```
×/¨1<⊂|⍳  Right argument: h w

       ⍳  Generate all index pairs (1-based) of a h×w array.
     ⊂    Enclose (h w), so it depth matches the one of the index array.
      |   For each pair (i j) compute the remainders of the division by (h w).
   1<     Compare all remainders with 1.
×/¨       Reduce each pair of Booleans by multiplication.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
2$lO6Lt4$(
```

This outputs an array containing zeros and ones.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MiRsTzZMdDQkKA&input=NQo3)

```
2$l    % Implicit inputs M, N. Generate M×N array of ones
O      % Push number 0
6Lt    % Push [2 -1] twice, corresponding to index "2:end-1"
4$(    % Fill the center of the array with value 0. Implicit display
```

---

For graphical output, add `1YG` at the end to display the array as an image  (**13 bytes**) :

```
2$Ol6Lt4$(1YG
```

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](http://matl.io/?code=2%24Ol6Lt4%24%281YG&inputs=5%0A7&version=16.1.0) For example,

```
>> matl 2$Ol6Lt4$(1YG
> 5
> 7
```

produces

[image]

Comment: @Sp3000 You're right... I couldn't resist :-) Anyway, the OP has clarified that an array or ASCII art with any characters is valid output

Comment: @LuisMendo great work, but it has to have two values passes to the method

Comment: @CreativeMagic Sorry. Corrected now. Maybe rephrase the challenge? "_Square_ ring" may be confusing

Comment: @LuisMendo not trying to make an excuse, but English is not my first language, if you can give me a better title, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: @CreativeMagic Maybe "rectangular ring" instead of "square ring"?

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks, I've edited ^.^ Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CreativeMagic No problem!

Comment: @LuisMendo Should inputs of 1 and 1 return a value of 1 or 0?

Comment: @Suever According to the first image in the OP, the output is 1 in that case

Comment: According to my interpretation the graphical output would be invalid as the tiles should not form a solid line.

Comment: @Neil The OP says _Cannot be a line_. I took that as "it cannot be a line without the appropriate thickness, corresponding to one tile". I'll ask them

Comment: So yes, one-tile thick line is valid

Comment: @CreativeMagic Thanks for the accept, but there's a shorter answer now

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
@(x)conv2(ones(x),eye(3),'s')>2
```

This creates an anonymous function which can then be run as `ans([4 5])` within the workspace.

Input is `[height, width]` and output is a matrix with 1 in the center and 0 for the boundary.

The way that this works is a matrix of ones the size of the input is created. It is then convolved with a 3 x 3 identify matrix with ones on the diagonal. We use the `same` input to `conv2` (shortened to `'s'` here) to keep the result the same size as the input.

We then want to convert the output to a binary value with 0 around the boundary and 1 inside. We use the inequality `>2` because all edge pixels will have a result < 3 and all non-boundary elements will have a result equal to 3.

For graphical output:

```
@(x)imagesc(conv2(ones(x),eye(3),'s')>8)
ans([6,9])
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
2$l3XyZ+3=
```

Input arguments are height and width as integers. The output is a matrix of size `height x width` where the boundary tiles are 0 and the inner values are 1.

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MiRsM1h5WiszPQ&input=NQo2)

**Explanation**

Same logic as my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77990/51939) with fewer bytes.

```
        % Grab two input parameters implicitly
2$l     % Create a matrix of ones that has the dimensions specified as inputs
3       % Number literal 3
Xy      % Create a 3x3 identity matrix
Z+      % Perform 2D convolution (preserving size)
3=      % Create a logical matrix where values == 3 are 1 and 0 otherwise (boundary)
        % Implicitly display output.
```

Answer (score 4):

### HTML/JS/CSS, <s>198</s> 194 bytes

Graphical output version. The byte count doesn't include `f=` nor the three `<input>` elements which are used for demonstration purposes only. Saved 3 bytes thanks to @IsmaelMiguel.

```js
f=(n,m)=>{with(d.style)width=n*25+'px',height=m*25+'px'}
```

```html
<input id=w placeholder=width><input id=h placeholder=height><input type=button value=Go! onclick=f(w.value,h.value)>
<div id=d style="border-image:radial-gradient(#fff 0,#fff 0)0 fill/25px;background:radial-gradient(#000 0,#000 8px,#fff 9px)0 0/25px 25px">
```

Comment: Can't `f=(n,m)=>{d.style.width=n*25+'px';d.style.height=m*25+'px';}` be simplified to `f=(n,m)=>with(d.style)width=n*25+'px',height=m*25+'px';`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The `with` does save me 3 bytes but I still need the `{}`s. On the other hand the `;` is unnecessary so I removed that too.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
p%€,>1P€G
```

Returns a grid of **0**'s (border) and **1**'s (interior). [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=cCXigqwsPjFQ4oKsc0c&input=&args=NQ+Ng)

#### How it works

```
p%€,>1P€sG  Main link. Arguments: h (height), w (width)

p           Cartesian product; return all pairs in [1, ..., h] × [1, ..., w].
   ,        Yield the pair [h, w].
 %€         For each pair [i, j] in the product, compute [i % h, j % w].
    >1      Compare all resulting moduli with 1.
      P€    Compute the product of each pair of Booleans.
        s   Split the resulting flat list into rows of length w.
         G  Display the results in a 2D grid.
```

Comment: This answer is great, but it has to visually be a rectangular ring. While it's fine to use arrays, strings etc., it has to look like a ring on the screen when you run it.

Comment: OK. When I read that 2D arrays were allowed, I didn't expect their visual representation to matter. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Dennis "[I]t has to look like a ring on the screen when you run it". That means spaces should be used?

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>46</s> 34 bytes

```
f(n,m)=[n>i>1<j<m for i=1:n,j=1:m]
```

This is a function that accepts two integers and returns a 2-dimensional boolean array.

We construct an *n* × *m* matrix using an array comprehension with a double `for` loop. For each index from 1 to *n* and 1 to *m*, i.e. each element of the matrix, we set the value to `true` if *n* > *i* > 1 and 1 < *j* < *m*. This is true everywhere but the boundaries, so the resulting array will have `true`s in the middle and `false`s around the border.

Examples:

```
julia> f(n,m)=[n>i>1<j<m for i=1:n,j=1:m]
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(4,4)
4x4 Array{Bool,2}:
 false  false  false  false
 false   true   true  false
 false   true   true  false
 false  false  false  false

julia> f(1,1)
1x1 Array{Bool,2}:
 false

julia> f(2,5)
2x5 Array{Bool,2}:
 false  false  false  false  false
 false  false  false  false  false
```

Saved 12 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
*/&(<:*@|i.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/7X01TRsrLQcajL1NP9rcinpKain2VqpK@go1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrmCukKVhCmOrqENoUKGSKKmQEFDL@DwA)

Coming back to this, almost 3 years later.  An idea inspired by Dennis answer, though not a translation.

- `i.` Create 0 based index lists from each arg
- `<: |` remainders when divided by the arg minus 1
- `*@` signup the results.  Now, eg, if an arg was 4, we'll have a list like `0 1 1 0`
- `*/` Create a multiplication table of those lists.

### Original Answer, 16 bytes

```
0(<2#<<0 _1)}$&1
```

Use shape `$` to create a rectangle of all ones the size of the inputs, and then use the complementary form of Amend `}` to turn the interior to zeros.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/w00bIyUbWwMFOINNWtV1Az/a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkK6QpmCtYQpjq6jAhUwXT/wA)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
jQ]Uajt%!RQt%!|
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=jQ%5DUajt%25%21RQt%25%21%7C&input=5%0A4)

Explanation:

```
                - Q = eval_input()
j               - j = eval_input()
jQ]             - [Q,j]
   U            - create a 3d array sized Q by j with coords
    a           - for each coord (2d for)
     jt%!       -   not (coord_1 % j-1)
              | -  ^ or V
          Qt%!  -   not (coord_2 % Q-1)
```

For prettified output, [use this code](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=jQ%5DUajt%25!RQt%25!%7C%29P&input=3%0A4).

Or 13 bytes with a zeroed out mask round the edge (middle chars non-zero)

```
jQ]Uajt%RQt%&
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=jQ%5DUajt%25RQt%25%26&input=5%0A5)

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 20 bytes

```
l~S*a*{3a.f|W%z}4*N*
```

Input should be in the form `height width`, output is an ASCII grid using spaces for the centre and `#` for the boundary.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~S*a*%7B3a.f%7CW%25z%7D4*N*&input=4%205)

#### Explanation

```
l~       e# Read and evaluate input, dumping h and w on the stack.
S*       e# Create a string of w spaces.
a*       e# Create an array of h copies of that string.
{        e# Repeat this block 4 times...
  3a.f|  e#   For each character in the first row, take its bitwise OR with 3, turning
         e#   spaces into # and leaving # unchanged.
  W%z    e#   Reverse and transpose the grid, rotating it by 90 degrees.
}4*
N*       e# Join the lines of the result with linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 80 <s>82 85</s>

**Edit** 3 bytes saved thx @Neil
**Edit** 2 bytes saved using `reduce` for once

Anonymous function returning a multi line string

```js
(w,h)=>[...Array(h)].reduce(o=>o+(w>1?'O'+' O'[!--h|!o].repeat(w-2):'')+`O
`,'')
```

**Test**

```js
f=(w,h)=>[...Array(h)].reduce(o=>o+(w>1?'O'+' O'[!--h|!o].repeat(w-2):'')+`O
`,'')

function test(){
  var [w,h] = I.value.match(/\d+/g)
  w=+w,h=+h // convert to numeric
  O.textContent=f(w,h)
}  

test()
```

```html
<input value='5 4' id=I><button onclick='test()'>Test</button><pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Surely `!--h|!o` is already an integer? Otherwise, I like the use of `!o`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 63 bytes

Anonymous function, prints to STDOUT. Border is `#`.

```
->x,y{h=?#;puts t=h*x,y>1?[[h+(x<2?'':' '*(x-2)+h)]*(y-2),t]:p}
```

Comment: Sorry, you must output a ring, so no backticks allowed inside.

Comment: And there goes the one byte I had been hoping to save by filling the inside with a small less-noticeable character...

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5, 45 + 1 (`-p`) = 46 bytes

```
$_=join$/,(1x$_)x<>;1while s/
.+\K1(?=.+
)/ /
```

following 45 bytes doesn't handle tileY=1

```
$_=1x<>.$/;say$_.s/(?!^.|.$)./ /gr x(<>-2).$_
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYrPzNPRV9Hw7BCJV6zwsbO2rA8IzMnVaFYn0tPO8bbUMPeVk@bS1NfQf//f1Muk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 97 bytes

```
(n,m)=>Array(n).fill(' '.repeat(m).replace(/^ | $/g,0)).join`
`.replace(/^.+|.+$/g,'0'.repeat(m))
```

Creates a ring of `0`s. Probably a terrible approach but I wanted to avoid edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```js
h=>w=>[...Array(i=h)].map(_=>(a=Array(w).fill(h-i--&&i?0:1),a[0]=a[w-1]=1,a))
```

Comment: I don't like the array of array output (even if it's allowed). What I see in console is `f(4)(4)` -> `Array [ Array[4], Array[4], Array[4], Array[4] ]`

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```
\d+
$*
S_`1(?=.* (1+))|.
T`1`#`^.+|.+$|.?¶.
```

Input should be in the form `height width`, output is an ASCII grid using `1` for the centre and `#` for the boundary.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqClNfYDEoPz0uKiAoMSspKXwuClRgMWAjYF4uK3wuKyR8Lj_Cti4&input=NCA1)

#### Explanation

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert each number `N` to a string of `N` ones (i.e. convert the input to unary).

```
S_`1(?=.* (1+))|.
```

Match each `1` in `height` and replace it with `width`, while also matching everything else and removing it. We do this by abusing a split stage. This creates a `w x h` grid.

```
T`1`#`^.+|.+$|.?¶.
```

Finally we replace every `1` with a `#` that is either found in the first line, the last line or at the beginning or end of a line.

Answer (score 1):

### [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/tree/v2), 23 bytes

```
;'#*;))¬' *'#;)@+(+nXX(
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OycjKjspKcKsJyAqJyM7KUArKCtuWFgo&input=Mwo0)

This approach is very similar to my approach in [this related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73646/45941).

Explanation:

```
;'#*;))¬' *'#;)@+(+nXX(
                         (implicit) push all input to stack
;'#*                     push a string containing X #s
    ;))                  dupe, and push both to bottom of stack
       ¬' *              push a string containing (X-2) spaces
           '#;)@+(+      add a # to the front and the back of the string
                   nXX   make (Y-2) copies
                      (  bring one of the "#"*X strings back to the top
                         (implicit) pop and print each stack item, separated by newlines
```

Comment: If Seriously v3 isn't called *Wait, Really?* I'll be quite disappointed.

Comment: @AlexA. Did you *seriously* just?

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, <s>107</s> <s>105</s> 97 bytes

```
DECLARE @ INT=3,@y INT=5

PRINT REPLICATE(1,@)+ISNULL('
'+REPLICATE('1'+ISNULL(SPACE(@-2),'')+'1
',@y-2)+REPLICATE(1,@),'')
```

> 1. generating first line
> 2. adding hollow lines + line breaks
> 3. adding last line(when needed)

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, 69 bytes

```
INPUT x,y
FOR i=1TO y
FOR j=1TO x
?i MOD y<2OR j MOD x<2;
NEXT
?
NEXT
```

Takes dimensions as `width,height`. The boolean value from the is-it-on-the-border test is simply printed: `-1` for true and `0` for false. A sample run looks like:

```
? 5,3
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1  0  0  0 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**Bonus: Graphical version, 88 bytes**

```
INPUT x,y
SCREEN 9
FOR i=1TO y
FOR j=1TO x
PSET(j*3,i*3),i MOD y<2OR j MOD x<2
NEXT
NEXT
```

I believe this counts as "not a line." When the `MOD` expression is false (0), `PSET` plots a black pixel; when it's true (-1), `PSET` apparently plots a white pixel. Here's `17,31`, shown at 2x size:

[image: Graphical rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

## [Unicorn](https://www.theedkins.co.uk/jo/games/unicorn/unicorn.htm), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
P3G$PG@PS@S$L2B$T1B@T1N
```

<sup>Because who doesn't like unicorns?!</sup>

Explanation ("list program" output):

```
P3  Paint current square with 3
G$P Get: sets $ from input P
G@P Get: sets @ from input P
S@  Subtract 1 from @
S$  Subtract 1 from $
L2  ~Loop 2 times
B$  ~Brush $ more square
T1  ~Turn 1 right angle clockwise
B@  ~Brush @ more square
T1  ~Turn 1 right angle clockwise
N   ~Next (loop)
```

Output for `tilesX` = 3, `tilesY` = 5:

[image]

Note: This version only works for `tilesX` up to 6 and `tilesY` up to 5. The question does not mention what range we need to support though, so I'm assuming this is OK. Otherwise, a small addition to the program produces this alternative, which supports a slightly larger range:

## Unicorn, <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
x0y9P3G$PG@PS@S$L2B$T1B@T1N
```

By adding `x0y9`, which starts the box at (0,9), the program works for `tilesX` up to 9 and `tilesY` up to 9 (because input only goes up to 9).

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 76 + 1 (`-a`) = 77 bytes

```perl
print(1x($a=$F[0]),$/,((1,$"x($a-2),1 x($a>1),$/)x($F[1]-2),1x$a)x($F[1]>1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvRMOwQkMl0VbFLdogVlNHRV9HQ8NQR0UJJKhrpKljqABi2RmCpDSBTLdow1iweIVKIowPlNX8/99UwfhffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0OD/7qJAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
«¾6ÅÈΛ
```

Input as a pair of integers, where the first is the height and the second is the width.
Outputs with `0` as characters.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0OpD@8wOtx7uODf7//9oYx3TWAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
     Λ  # Use the Canvas builtin with the following three options:
        # (after which the resulting shape is output implicitly immediately afterwards)
«       # - line lengths: use the (implicit) input-integer, merged with itself: [h,w,h,w]
  6ÅÈ   # - the directions: push a list of even integers <= 6: [0,2,4,6]
 ¾      # - what to draw: push the counter variable, which is 0 by default
```

The Canvas builtin uses three arguments to draw a shape:

- Character/string to draw: character `0`, which could alternatively be `1`/`2` by replacing the `¾` with `X`/`Y` respectively.
- Length of the lines we'll draw: the input-list twice. Since there is more than one input-length, these are leading for the Canvas builtin, so we'll need the additional merge `«` at the start, otherwise it would only draw the top and left borders, instead of the entire box.
- The direction to draw in: `[0,2,4,6]`. The digits in the range \$[0,7]\$ each represent a certain direction:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

So the `[0,2,4,6]` in this case translate to the directions \$[↑,→,↓,←]\$.

Here a step-by-step explanation of the output (we'll use input-lengths `[3,5]` as example here):

Step 1: Draw 3 `0` characters in direction `0↑`:

```python
0
0
0
```

Step 2: Draw 5-1 `0` characters in direction `2→`:

```python
00000
0
0
```

Step 3: Draw 3-1 `0` characters in direction `4↓`:

```python
00000
0   0
0   0
```

Step 4: Draw 5-1 `0` characters in direction `6←`:

```python
00000
0   0
00000
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine for an in-depth explanation of the Canvas builtin.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
ＢＮＮ*
```

First input is the width, second input is the height.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98pv0LDM6@gtMSvNDcptUhDUweVp6SlpPn/vwmX8X/dshwA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nkXv96wDIq3//024jAE).

**Explanation:**

```
ＢＮＮ*
Box(InputNumber(),InputNumber(),"*")
```

Builtin: draw a box using the two input as width/height respectively and character `*` as border. (The `*` can be replaced with other ASCII characters that are available in the Charcoal codepage.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>71</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:[[n>i+1>1<j+1<m for i in range(n)]for j in range(m)]
```

Returns a 2 dimensional array. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcixCoAgEADQX7lR0UXCJcwfMQejLCVPEZe@/qKpN772jKviRHFZ6Q5l2wOgLLNzaJNQVpkslCkQa4cECaEHPA@G3H@T/yncU@sJB4tMS805Eb0)

Port of [Alex A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77995/109916)'s answer.

-4 thx to @Steffan

Comment: [63](https://tio.run/##RcixCoAgEADQX7lR0UXCJcwfMQejLCVPEZe@/qKpN772jKviRHFZ6Q5l2wOgLLNzaJNQVpkslCkQa4cECaEHPA@G3H@T/yncU@sJB4tMS805Eb0 "Python 3 – Try It Online")